# github actions can't access swift package

Tags: yaml, devops, github-actions, swift-package-manager

```
 # This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

 name: CI

 # Controls when the action will run. 
 on:
   # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
   push:
     #branches: [ main ]
   pull_request:
     branches: [ main ]

   # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
   workflow_dispatch:

 # A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
 jobs:
   # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
   build:
     # The type of runner that the job will run on
     runs-on: macos-latest

     # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
     steps:
       # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
       - uses: actions/checkout@v2

       - run: |
           pwd
           swift package init --type library
           xcodebuild clean
           xcodebuild test -project TimeFountain.xcodeproj -scheme TimeFountain CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS= DEVELOPMENT_TEAM= CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
```

The problem is that it isn't accessing the AlamoFire Swift Package which I committed into the project. The error I'm getting is:

```
...
error: no such module 'Alamofire'
1499
import Alamofire
1500
       ^
1501

1502
CompileSwift normal x86_64 
...
Error: Process completed with exit code 65.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: `test -project TimeFountain.xcodeproj`, I changed it to use the workspace.

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

       name: CI
       on:
         pull_request:
            branches:
         workflow_dispatch:

       # A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
       jobs:
         # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
         build:
           # The type of runner that the job will run on
           runs-on: macos-latest

           # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
           steps:
             # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
             - uses: actions/checkout@v2

             - run: |
                 pwd
                 swift package init --type library
                 xcodebuild clean
                 xcodebuild test -workspace TimeFountain.xcworkspace -scheme TimeFountain CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS= DEVELOPMENT_TEAM= CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
```